# Нестандартная разметка в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml, recyclerview

У меня тут появилась идея написать свою галерею и я увидел неплохую разметку но пока без понятия как ее реализовать , суть такая что хочу отображать картинки в recyclerview в таком виде (см картинку) , извиняюсь за мой дизайн , нужно чтобы вы подсказали как вообще такое можно сделать. Если  не совсем понятно что именно я хочу , то такую разметку я увидел в приложении Яндекс.Диск.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В принципе, в adapter в getView можно управлять каждым элементом отдельно, одни сделать низкие, другие высокие и поделить на части внутренними контейнерами, но зачем вообще пытаться подогнать этот хаос под RecyclerView?

Comment: @Rou1997 а как бы вы это реализовали , если не использовать recyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Положением элементов относительно друг друга занимается не сам `RecyclerView`, а `LayoutManager`, который устанавливается в список.

Можете попробовать поискать такой на https://android-arsenal.com/ .
Или напишите сами.

Также можно поиграться с `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, я думаю его можно довольно качественно приспособить к Вашей задаче.